# AWK reading path from text file

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, scripting

I have a file called ***path_resume.txt*** which contains some paths to other files.

Inside **path_resume.txt**:

```
./a2111oi/sky130_fd_sc_hd__a2111oi_0.txt
./a2111oi/sky130_fd_sc_hd__a2111oi_2.txt
./a2111oi/sky130_fd_sc_hd__a2111oi_4.txt
```

Each path points to another text file that has the same structure as follows:

```
HEAD
INFO
BEGIN sky130_fd_sc_hd__a2111oi_0
...
...
END BEGIN
END INFO
END HEAD
```

I am trying to read each of these .txt files from the path_resume.txt, copy all lines between **BEGIN** and **END BEGIN** and save incrementally to another file called output.txt:

```
BEGIN sky130_fd_sc_hd__a2111oi_0
...
...
END BEGIN
BEGIN sky130_fd_sc_hd__a2111oi_2
...
...
END BEGIN
BEGIN sky130_fd_sc_hd__a2111oi_4
...
...
END BEGIN
```

When I run:

```
awk '{while((getline a < $0)> 0) print a}' path_resume.txt
```

I can read each file from the path_resume.txt correctly, but I can't remove the unwanted lines.

When I run:

```
awk '/BEGIN/{flag=1}/END BEGIN/{flag=0}flag' ./a2111oi/sky130_fd_sc_hd__a2111oi_0.txt
 >> output.txt
```

I can remove the unwanted lines, however I had to pass the path to the file manually. I do not know how to merge the two comands to achieve my goal. I appreciate any help.

Comment: You got multiple answers to your question, please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next.

Answer (score 6):

You could build the same logic with the print/no-print flag inside the `while(getline)` loop. Something like this:

```
awk '{ while((getline a < $0) > 0) { 
    if (a ~ /BEGIN/) p=1;
    if (p) print a;
    if (a ~ /END BEGIN/) p=0;
} }' path_resume.txt > output.txt
```

The only thing here is that you need to explicitly use `if` statements, instead of implicit conditionals like you can on the top level of the AWK script.

Or in Bash, slurp the list of filenames to an array and pass them all to  AWK in one go:

```
readarray -t filenames < path_resume.txt
awk '/BEGIN/ {p=1}; p; /END BEGIN/ {p=0}' "${filenames[@]}" > output.txt
```

(I put the print action before the `END BEGIN` check to also print that end delimiter.)

Answer (score 4):

Something like the following, untested, will do what you want using any awk:

```
awk '
    NR == FNR { ARGV[ARGC++]=$0; next }
    $1 == "BEGIN" { f=1 }
    f
    $0 == "END BEGIN" { f=0 }
' path_resume.txt > output.txt
```

or this might be very slightly faster but see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline so you don't fall into the trap of using `getline` unnecessarily or incorrectly:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        file = ARGV[--ARGC]
        while ( (getline line < file) > 0 ) {
            ARGV[ARGC++] = line
        }
    }
    $1 == "BEGIN" { f=1 }
    f
    $0 == "END BEGIN" { f=0 }
' path_resume.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `xargs` (and without using double `awk` to read each line from the file) you can pass all the paths you have in your text file:

```bash
xargs awk  '/BEGIN/{flag=1}/END BEGIN/{print;flag=0}flag'  < path_resume.txt > out.txt
```

*I'm assuming the your file **path_resume.txt** does not contain spaces in any path*

In `awk` I used `{print;flag=0}` to also print the line `END BEGIN`.

---

If you had paths with spaces in their filenames then you can use this:

```bash
tr '\n' '\0' < path_resume.txt | xargs -0  awk  '/BEGIN/{flag=1}/END BEGIN/{print;print "";flag=0}flag' > out.txt
```

Comment: GNU xargs has `xargs -d '\n'` to read intact lines, but using `tr` to allow `-0` looks smart!

Comment: @ilkkachu oh, that's nice too!. I thought `-d '\n'` would not work. (I never tried but I supposed that).

Comment: translating newlines to NULs so xargs can process NUL-terminated lines is pointless vs just having xargs process newline-terminated lines. If a file name contained a newline in the middle of it then `tr '\n' '\0'` would convert that to a NUL and so break the file name so the only way translating newlines to NULs would work would be if none of the file names contained newlines but if that's the case they can just be processed as newline-terminated with `xargs -d '\n'`. Both `-0` and `-d` are GNU xargs extensions so using `-0` instead of `-d '\n'` wouldn't even be making the script more portable

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for pointing that out. I actually thought that xargs delimiter was not useful in this case, I was wrong, I see. Although parsing lines with `xargs -0` maybe useful only for blank spaces in terms of portability is not.

Comment: @EdMorton I can get the posix manual of `xargs` (as well as other commands) by using `man 1p xargs` for example, but is that useful to know how the command behaves/works in posix mode?

Comment: @EdMorton, except that telling xargs to read newline-terminated lines isn't that simple. `-d '\n'` is only available in GNU xargs, and e.g. `-L 1` would tell it to read one line, but it also enables trailing spaces to allow continuing a line to the next, so it doesn't process the lines intact. `-0` is more commonly supported (e.g.  the BSDs, and Busybox), and the `tr` solution works with that even if `-d` isn't available. The fact that the filenames here can't have newlines comes from the problem statement already, so it's hardly an issue with how xargs is used here.

Comment: @ikkachu I never suggested `-L`. Thanks for the info that `-d` is also supported on BSD and Busybox `xargs`.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon how any given command works in it's POSIX mode is different from the POSIX definition of a command, as we'd previously discussed, since even in "POSIX mode" any command can do whatever it likes with functionality that's undefined by POSIX (e.g. the value of `$0` in the `END` section of an awk script) and still be POSIX-compliant.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks, I think I only read posix manual of some commands to know what options are supported. Because if I read the `xargs` posix manual the `-0` option is not documented so I think that's useful to know if using some option is portable or no.

Comment: Could be. Until I read your comment I had no idea there was a `1p` option for man pages to show POSIX man pages, e.g. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1p.html, I always just read the POSIX spec directly e.g. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html, so I'm not sure how reliable those man pages are or if they're really intended to show POSIX functionality or how any given Linux command works in "posix" mode or something else. `xargs` looks the same to me in both but idk if that's true and/or if it applies to all tools.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all pathnames in the input file are properly quoted, concatenate all the listed files together and use `sed` to extract the parts between lines starting with `BEGIN` and end with `END BEGIN`:

```bash
xargs cat <path_resume.txt |
sed -n '/^BEGIN/,/^END BEGIN/p' >output.txt
```

This uses `xargs` to call `cat` with the sisted files in `path_resume.txt` as operands.  This creates a single stream of all data concatenated from all the files in the order listed in the input file.

The stream is then filtered by `sed` which prints all lines in the blocks we're interested in.

One could reformulate the `sed` expression so that it instead deletes all lines that occur outside of the blocks we're interested in (allowing us to drop the `-n` option):

```bash
xargs cat <path_resume.txt |
sed '/^BEGIN/,/^END BEGIN/!d' >output.txt
```

You could obviously also call `sed` *directly* from `xargs`:

```bash
xargs sed '/^BEGIN/,/^END BEGIN/!d' <path_resume.txt >output.txt
```

Or, using `awk`,

```bash
xargs awk '/^BEGIN/,/^END BEGIN/' <path_resume.txt >output.txt
```

Comment: If the input is properly quoted _for xargs_, that is. It follows slightly different quoting rules than the shells do, which probably only comes up in really weird cases, but it's annoyingly one more syntax to learn.

Answer (score -1):

How about this approach? It's kinda lazy, but it will do the job. You read the lines of `path_resume.txt` and use every line as a file for `awk` to work with

```
for i in `cat path_resume.txt`; do awk '/BEGIN/{flag=1}/END BEGIN/{flag=0}flag' $i >> output; done
```

Comment: that'll work for "nice" filenames, but it's worth noting that it doesn't take every line as a filename, but every whitespace separated string. E.g. if the file has the single line `foo bar`, that'll get treated as two filenames. Plus it'll try to expand any glob characters in the file, so better not do that if any filenames can contain any of `*?[]` at least.

Comment: you might even get away with `awk '/BEGIN/{flag=1}/END BEGIN/{flag=0}flag' $(cat path_resume.txt)` since awk can take multiple filenames to process. Though if one file is missing the `END BEGIN` part, the flag would be set from the start of the next file...

Comment: Emphasizing ilkkachu's comment: [don't read lines with "for"](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)